# How to subset (classify ) raster based on another raster grid cells values?

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, rasterizing

How to reclassify (subset) a raster `r1` ( of the same dimension and extent as `r2`) based on following conditions in `r2` in the given example.

Conditions:

- If the grid cells values of `r2` are `>0.5`, retain corresponding value and adjacent 2 grids cells next to 0.5 values (ie buffer the grid cells with values `>0.5` in `r2` to the surrounding two grids in all directions) in `r1` and change other values to 0.

ie. how can i change grid cells values in `r1` such that it gives those values which correspond to `>0.5` value grid cells and its buffering (surrounding) two grid cells in each direction in `r2`.

If I only had to get grid cells `>0.5` I would have easily obtained by the following code, however, I want to extract the `>0.5` value as well as the value of the 2 surrounding gridcells as well.

Sample example calculation code is :

```
set.seed(150)
r1 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=5) #Create rasters
values(r1) = round(runif(ncell(r1),5,25))
r2 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=5)
values(r2) = round(runif(ncell(r2),0.1,1))

selfun <- function(x,y) {
  ifelse( x >0.5, y,0)
}  # It works only for >0.5 gridcells, i need this gridcells and its adjacent
  #two gridcells in each direction.
# it's like buffering the >0.5 grid cells with adjacent two grids and retaining corresponding grid cells values.

r3<-overlay(r2,r1,fun=selfun)
plot(r3)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use the `focal` function to create a mask showing the pixels of interest, and use the `mask` function to retrieve the values.

I am going to create my examples because the example rasters you created are too small for demonstration.

```
# Create example raster r1
set.seed(150)
r1 <- raster(ncol = 100, nrow = 50) 
values(r1) <- round(runif(ncell(r1), 5, 25))

r1 <- crop(r1, extent(-60, 60, -30, 30))

plot(r1)
```

[image]

```
# Create example raster r2
r2 <- raster(ncol = 100, nrow = 50)
values(r2) <- rnorm(ncell(r2), mean = -1)

r2 <- crop(r2, extent(-60, 60, -30, 30))

plot(r2)
```

[image]

The first step is to process `r2` by replacing any values larger than 0.5 to be 1 and others to be `NA`.

```
# Replace values > 0.5 to be 1, others to be NA
r2[r2 > 0.5] <- 1
r2[r2 <= 0.5] <- NA

plot(r2)
```

[image]

Before using the `focal` function, we need to define a matrix representing the window and a function.

```
# Define a matrix as the window
w <-  matrix(c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
               NA, 1, 1, 1, NA,
               1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
               NA, 1, 1, 1, NA,
               NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), ncol = 5)
# Define a function to populate the maximum values when w = 1
max_fun <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) if (all(is.na(x))) NA else max(x, na.rm = na.rm)
```

We can then apply the `focal` function.

```
r3 <- focal(r2, w = w, fun = max_fun, pad = TRUE)

plot(r3)
```

[image]

`r3` is a layer showing the pixels we want values from `r1`. We can now use the `mask` function for this.

```
# Use the mask function extract values in r1 based on r3
r4 <- mask(r1, r3)
# Replace NA with 0
r4[is.na(r4)] <- 0

plot(r4)
```

`r4` is the final output.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but how did you define the window matrix?

Comment: You can print the matrix w and see the structure. You said you want the adjacent two grid cells. I thought this could mean all directions (up, down, left, right), but I am not sure the condition of the diagonal. My example matrix assumes one cell for the diagonal, but you can modify the matrix based on your needs.